# How to I get a USB keyboard to work with GRUB on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, usb, keyboard

I have a new machine (AMD 3960X with a MSI motherboard).  I have 4 separate drives with different OS's (Ubuntu 20.04, Windows 10 and 2 versions of Ubuntu 16.04).  I keep then completely independent on separate physical drives.  I use Ubuntu 20.04 as my primary boot device (the one that Grub runs from).  When I boot, I have no keyboard access, so it boots to the most recent usd OS.  The workaround to change OS's is the when I am in the Grub boot menu (i.e. for 10 seconds), if I plug a USB pen drive into a USB port, the keyboard starts working.  Unplugging and re-plugging in either the mouse or keyboard doesn't work.  There is something about plugging in a USB drive that causes the USB ports to be reset, or something similar.
I have seen this problem in the past, and the fix has always been bios settings to enable legacy devices and disable hand-off.  This doesn't work.  There are no USB2.0 ports on the motherboard, only USB3.x.  I have also tried preloading various modules in grub (usb, usb_keyboard, usbms, usbtest).  None of them make any difference.
I don't think it has anything to do with Ubuntu versions (16.04 does the same).  I think it is a problem that grub has with recent hardware.  Has anyone else seen this problem and have a fix?

Comment: The USB keyboard needs to be connected to a system USB port, not a USB card port, or a Logitech wireless config.

Comment: UEFI has an internal driver, both Windows & Ubuntu have their own keyboard drivers. But grub relies on the UEFI driver, but you may have to turn on allow USB full use or USB keyboard & mouse setting in UEFI. My Asus motherboard has several USB settings that I have to have on, not sure about MSI. Have you updated UEFI from MSI? https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2398599

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem I updated the bios from v2.00 to v2.50 but I don't think that made any difference.  With the newer bios, I found that if I pressed a key (I used the escape key) just after the numlock light comes on, but before the post beep then the keyboard usually works in Grub.  There is some timing with the keypress, but I got used to it fairly quickly.  If you press the key after the post boot then the keyboard won't work until the OS boots up.  It's not the best solution, but it's better than plugging and unplugging a USB key.  I think the keypress causes the USB device to be used so it initializes correctly.
I am posting this so that anyone with a similar problem will know where to look.
The motherboard is a MSI TRX40 Pro Wifi, but I suspect it isn't specific to this brand or this model.  The CPU is a AMD 3960X.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. Reinstalled XUbuntu 20.04 after Windows-10 update trashed Linux partition & now keyboard (US layout) doesn't work at boot and only partially once Linux loads.

Keyboard is an expensive (well $80 or $90) wired Logitech USB which I really like.  It's always worked before and can do some simple stuff with OpenOffice after boot. Can't log on to Stack Exchange tho; need to use cell phone.